Having issue in adding custom Drop down in Pluto Grid Flutter
I am using the same drop down and it is working everywhere except the pluto grid the issue is that I am not able to type in the textfield which is customly made or in the dropdown field.
PlutoColumn(
          title: 'Account Code',
          field: 'account_code',
          enableAutoEditing: true,
          enableEditingMode: true,
          applyFormatterInEditing: true,
          checkReadOnly: (row, cell) => checkCellReadOnly(row, cell),
          type: PlutoColumnType.text(),
          renderer: (rendererContext) => SearchableDropdownRenderer(
            context: rendererContext,
            items: accNums,
            text:
                rendererContext.row.cells[rendererContext.column.field]!.value,
            onChanged: (value) {
              rendererContext.row.cells[rendererContext.column.field]!.value =
                  value;
            }, // Pass your list of cost center 4 names here
          ),
          enableRowDrag: true,
        ),

`
I have tried the same drop down in the screen it is working in the sync fusion table it is working it is specifically not working in the plutogrid I am not able to type in this field or any other simple field

Check this https://github.com/doonfrs/pluto_grid_plus/issues/58, maybe it can help with your problem

There could be an issue if you have a complex nested layout. You have to debug step by step.
First, let’s debug using the onChange property of the TextField.
Print the value returned by the onChange method.
Let me know if you see any logs while typing.

I didn't see any log while typing
